# Text on image not displaying

Tags: css

Text on my image is not appearing. Its animating but i want text on my image on mouse hover. For text I used button with image that suppose to popup on mouse hover.let me know my mistake. I am using this code from youtube tutorial.

```css
.main 
{
 border: 10px solid white;
 width:378px;
 height:250px;
 margin:50px auto;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 25px black;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.main:hover img 
{
-webkit-transform:scale(2,2) rotate(45deg);
}

.main:hover .content 
{
-webkit-transform:translate(-311px);
}

img 
{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms; 
}

.content 
{ 
 width:378px;
  height:250px;
 background: rgba(124,120,120,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms;
}
   
   button 
   {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:200px;
    background:black;
    border:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    font:16px tahoma;
   }
   
   button:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
   }
```

```html
<div class="main"><img src="img/switch.jpg" height="250" width="378"><div class="content"><button>Pepe Kalvier Switches</button></div></div>
```

Comment: your image is not loading correctly

Comment: Please check it my answer

Comment: the problem is with your `.main` height and why there is `margin-top:200px;` in button

Comment: @Amitsingh you have to place any image with it.

Comment: @Amitsingh margin-top:200px; is to leave space from top so that image will display in bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the position absolute to move your text/button above the image when hover.

**CSS**

```
.main:hover .content{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bsq769v9/10/)**

Comment: After changing as you suggest, Now my text is on the image as default. I want it to come only when i mouse hover.

Comment: `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 300ms;` really?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This code is not mine...yeah its wrong...the comment should be to the OP

Comment: I tried. Now when i hover my mouse, it appears for a second and slides away with the animation of the pic.

Comment: @AliSultan You had a error in your animation code...i edited your animation errors...check my demo again

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<div class="main"><img src="http://dev.boutiquevalmont.com/media/wysiwyg/valmont/arts/thb3.jpg" height="250" width="378"><div class="content"><button>Pepe Kalvier Switches</button></div></div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/h5bhrx7x/1/)